# Using results from one RethinkDB query in another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I want to send a http post with an address, which will grab a doc from the database. I would like to then use that doc's geodata in a getNearest function, ultimately returning the nearest four other locations. How do I go about stringing these two queries together?

```js
r.table('dealer_locations').filter(function(dealer) {
return {
      dealer :  ("Address").match(request.body.Address)
      .getNearest(dealer, {
            index: 'geodata',
            maxResults: 4
          })
      }
    }).run(conn, function(error, cursor) {
      if (error) {
        handleError(response, error);
      } else {
        cursor.toArray(function(error, results) {
          if (error) {
            handleError(response, error);
          } else {
            response.send(results);
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? It would be easier to work with a starting point. It might also clarify some questions one might have about the setup.

Comment: Added some code above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll reformulate the question just to make a bit more clear:

**Problem**

Given a specific document with geodata, I want to also return the four nearest locations to that location.

**Solution**

First, make sure that you've creating the geo index in the table you want to query:

```
r.table('dealer_locations').indexCreate('location', { geo: true })
```

After that, make sure that you've inserted a [`r.point`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/point/) object into the document. You can't just use geo indexes on just any property. They have to be `r.point`s.

```
r.table('dealer_locations')
  .insert({
    name: 'San Francisco', 
    location: r.point(37.774929, -122.419416)
  })
```

After you've inserted all your documents and they all have [`r.point`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/point/)s property on the same property you created an index for, now you can start querying them.

If you want to get all the nearest locations for a location, you can do as follows:

```
r.table('dealer_locations')
 .filter({ name: 'San Francisco' })(0)
 .do(function (row) {
   return r.table('dealer_locations')
     .getNearest(row('location'), { index: 'location', maxResults: 4 })
 })
```

If you want to append the closets locations to a document, so that you can return both the document and the nearest locations at the same time, you can do that using the [`merge`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/merge/) method.

```
r.table('dealer_locations')
 .filter({ name: 'San Francisco' })(0)
 .merge(function (row) {
   return {
     nearest_locations: r.table('dealer_locations')
       .getNearest(row('location'), { index: 'location', maxResults: 4 })
   }
 })
```

Finally, if you want to get all the nearest locations, based on an address (supposing your document has both an `address` property with a string and a `location` property with an `r.point`), you can do something like this:

```
r.table('dealer_locations')
 .filter(r.row('address').match(request.body.Address))
 (0) // Only get the first document
 .do(function (row) {
   // Return the 4 documents closest to the 'location' if the previous document
   return r.table('dealer_locations')
     .getNearest(row('location'), { index: 'location', maxResults: 4 })
 })
```

That being said, the problem with this might be that you might match multiple addresses which are not necessarily the ones you want to match!

Comment: This solution is a little different than what I needed but you pointed me in the right enough direction to where I figured the rest out. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Just out of curiosity, what was different?

Comment: I needed to integrate creating the index with the insert so it could be done all in one function (uploading an excel spreadsheet). I do have one question though, about your last code snippet. I am wanting to return the 4 closest addresses to the one I give in the request body, but currently I am only returning 1. Is this due to the (0) you have behind the filter?

Comment: What the 0 does, is that it makes sure you are only getting the 4 nearest documents for the first match. You should make sure you're actually matching a document with the `filter` function and make sure you have enough documents in the `getNearest`.

Comment: I tried it with some of my own data, and it does return 4 documents if there is a match and there are enough documents with the location property.

Comment: Okay, yeah it's working now, I think I had some values swapped around in mine. Thanks, good solution!